# sar -P ALL command AIX 6.1

Tags: aix, cpu

What is the meaning of `-` in the `cpu` column below? Is it average of all CPU cores?

```
bash-3.00$ sar -P ALL 2 2
AIX tinapp1 1 6 00F6F78B4C00    11/27/13
System configuration: lcpu=4  mode=Capped
19:02:54 cpu    %usr    %sys    %wio   %idle   physc
19:02:56  0       13      15       0      72    0.30
          1        0       1       0      99    0.23
          2        0       0       0     100    0.24
          3        0       0       0     100    0.23
          -        4       5       0      91    1.01
19:02:58  0       12      15       0      73    0.29
          1        2       1       0      97    0.24
          2        0       0       0     100    0.23
          3        0       1       0      99    0.23
          -        4       5       0      91    1.00
Average   0       13      15       0      72    0.30
          1        1       1       0      98    0.24
          2        0       0       0     100    0.24
          3        0       1       0      99    0.23
          -        4       5       0      91    1.01
bash-3.00$ sar -P ALL 2 3
AIX tinapp1 1 6 00F6F78B4C00    11/27/13
System configuration: lcpu=4  mode=Capped
19:03:02 cpu    %usr    %sys    %wio   %idle   physc
19:03:04  0        9      11       0      80    0.28
          1        1       1       0      99    0.24
          2        0       0       0     100    0.24
          3        0       0       0      99    0.24
          -        3       3       0      94    1.00
19:03:06  0        9      10       0      81    0.28
          1        0       1       0      99    0.24
          2        0       0       0     100    0.24
          3        0       1       0      99    0.24
          -        3       3       0      94    1.00
19:03:08  0       12      16       1      70    0.30
          1        0       1       0      99    0.23
          2        0       1       0      99    0.23
          3        0       0       0     100    0.23
          -        4       5       0      91    1.00
Average   0       10      13       0      77    0.29
          1        0       1       0      99    0.24
          2        0       0       0     100    0.24
          3        0       0       0      99    0.24
          -        3       4       0      93    1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`sar` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/sar.htm):

> the last line indicates system-wide statistics for all processors

So indeed the percentage columns are averages over all processors. The `physc` column is the total over all processors.